# Local variable not used warning when passing it parameters

Tags: android

I declare a file as such:

```
File song = new File(path, "SpaceJam.mp3");
```

Use it in a function below:

```
public void hitplay(View button){
        playSong(song);
}
```

And then use it in the playSong function:

```
public void  playSong(File music){
        // Play song
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(music.toString());
            mp.prepare();
            . . .
```

But I'm told by eclipse that the song variable isn't used, even though it is passed into playSong and used in setDataSource.

Am I missing something or can I ignore this warning?

Comment: the second method indicates that you are using some field variable.

Comment: So the "song" in playSong(song) is different than the one declared? Could you explain what you mean a bit more?

Comment: The method `httpplay(View button)` takes a `View` object. But there is no `song` object being passed, which in turn is being passed to method `playSong(File music)`. Unless it is an oversight when posting. With only snippets of code it is hard to tell why Eclipse complains.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore this warning. 
Or you can do this:

above onCreate

```
File song = null;
```

then do this

```
song = new File(path, "SpaceJam.mp3");
```

Comment: I tried setting song to null above onCreate and the warning remains, but I'll ignore it for now. Thanks.